# rails ajax success not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

On Rails, I'm trying to create infinity like button which enable users to like multiple times, but Ajax seems not working. Here are my codes.

app/views/posts/_like.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'B', post_like_path({:id => @post}), :class => 'like', :method => :post, :remote => true %>
```

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
def like
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.like += 1
  post.save
  if request.xhr?
    puts 'test' #'test' appears when like clicked
  else
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

app/assets/javascript/application.js

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', function(e) {
  console.log('test1') // 'test1' does not appear!!!
});
console.log('test2') // 'test2' does appear
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting your puts statement to show, it seems like you aren't too far away, but your like route needs to respond to your ajax request. In order to do that, I would set up a respond_to block inside your like method

```
def like
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.like += 1
  post.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

With this, you would then create a js template, app/views/posts/like.js.erb

```
#like.js.erb
console.log('like clicked');
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple issues that i see, your use of the path_helper you aren't instantiating @post as a variable (at least not from what you've shown), also your ajax method should probably look closer to this ...

```
#app/views/posts/_like.html.erb
<%= link_to 'B', post_like_path(:id => @post.id), :class => 'like', :method => :post, :remote => true %>    

#config/routes.rb
get "/some-path", to: "posts#index"
post "/some-path", to: "posts#like", as: "post_like"

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def index
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def like
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.like += 1
  post.save
end

#app/assets/javascript/application.js
$(".like").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  url = $(this).attr('href');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    success: console.log('success')
  });
});
```